# What is "&=" used for in JS?

Tags: javascript

See this code:

```
var bFormValid = true;
var bValidData = true;

if(x < y){
    bValidData = false;
}

bFormValid &= bValidData;
```

Any ideas what the line `bFormValid &= bValidData;` is doing? I've never seen `&=` like that...

Comment: It's equivalent to `bFormValid = bFormValid & bValidData;`

Comment: [For your bookmark collection.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

Comment: @Pointy wow... that's a lot of info to sort through

Comment: @FastTrack well, yes, like any language spec it's pretty long, but it's the ultimate authority :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like `foo += 5` is equivalent to `foo = foo + 5`, `foo &= bar` is equivalent to `foo = foo & bar`.

`&`, of course, is the [bitwise AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) (not to be confused with the boolean AND operator, `&&`).

By way of example:

```
var a = 5,  // 5 is '101' in binary, or 101b for short
    b = 6,  // 6 is 110b
    result;

result = a & b;      // set 'result' to the result of the binary
                     // operation '101b AND 110b'
console.log(result)  // => 4 ('100' in binary)

a &= b;          // set 'a' to the result of '101b AND 110b'
console.log(a);  // => 4 (same as before, but we changed 'a' instead of
                 //       assigning the result to another variable)
```

This works with most operators in JavaScript:

```
var foo = 6; // 110b

foo |= 9;  // foo = 110b OR 1001b - 'foo' is now 15 (1111b)
foo -= 5;  // foo = foo - 5       - 'foo' is now 10
foo /= 2;  // foo = foo / 2       - 'foo' is now 5
foo %= 3;  // foo = foo % 3       - 'foo' is now 2
```

It doesn't work with the boolean operators, though:

```
var bar = true;

bar ||= false;
// => SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an '[augmented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment)' [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

```
bFormValid &= bValidData;
```

Is equivalent to

```
bFormValid = bFormValid & bValidData;
```

Where `&` here is the [bitwise AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, that operator performs a bitwise AND operation.  Another thing to note, with that code in particular, is that it starts off with *Boolean* values, and ends up with a *number*:

```
var bFormValid = true;
var bValidData = true;

if(x < y){
    bValidData = false;
}

bFormValid &= bValidData;
```

At the end of that sequence, the variable "bFormValid" will be either zero or one, *not* `true` or `false`. Does that matter? Well, maybe, maybe not. If it's desirable that it be really boolean:

```
bFormValid = !!(bFormValid & bValidData);
```

Alternatively, it could be numeric all the way through:

```
var bFormValid = 1;
var bValidData = 1;

if(x < y){
    bValidData = 0;
}

bFormValid &= bValidData;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the bitwise & assignment operator. It sets the result of a bitwise AND operation on the value of a variable and the value of an expression. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9h8y72a%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)